# Handlebars: TypeError: Cannot read property 'helperMissing' of undefined

Tags: javascript, templates, gulp, handlebars.js, precompiled-templates

I am having a problem with Handlebars compiled templates.  I feel like I am completely missing something important, but try as I might, I can't seem to work it out, or find any information online as to why this particular situation is presenting itself.

I am compiling using a Gulp task using gulp-handlebars.  The gulp task is:

```
gulp.task('build-hbs', function(){
  gulp.src('root/app/src/hbs/*.hbs')
  .pipe(handlebars())
  .on('error', notify.onError({
    message: 'Error: <%= error.message %>'
  }))
  .pipe(declare({
    namespace: 'Handlebars.templates',
    noRedeclare: true // Avoid duplicate declarations
  }))
  .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('root/app/js/templates/'));
});
```

for simple templates things are working OK, however I am now trying to use a simple helper (Note: when working with non-compiled templates, the helper works fine).  The helper is:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('gravatar', function(hash, size) {
  var grav = '<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hash + '.jpg?r=g&d=mm&s=' + size + '">';
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(grav);
});
```

The template itself looks like this:

```
<div id="nick"><b>{{display}}</b></div>
<div id="image">{{gravatar hash}}</div>
```

Once compiled, I get:

```
this["Handlebars"] = this["Handlebars"] || {};
this["Handlebars"]["templates"] = this["Handlebars"]["templates"] || {};
this["Handlebars"]["templates"]["profile"] = {"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    var helper, alias1=helpers.helperMissing, alias2="function", alias3=this.escapeExpression;

  return "<div id=\"nick\">\r\n  <b>"
    + alias3(((helper = (helper = helpers.display || (depth0 != null ? depth0.display : depth0)) != null ? helper : alias1),(typeof helper === alias2 ? helper.call(depth0,{"name":"display","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
    + "</b>\r\n</div>\r\n<div id=\"image\">\r\n  <img src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/"
    + alias3(((helper = (helper = helpers.hash || (depth0 != null ? depth0.hash : depth0)) != null ? helper : alias1),(typeof helper === alias2 ? helper.call(depth0,{"name":"hash","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
    + "?s=32\">\r\n</div>";
},"useData":true};
```

Within my JS code, I do something like:

```
$('#profile').html(Handlebars.templates.profile({
    display:'user 1',
    hash:'abdcef....'
}));
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'helperMissing' of undefined
```

Which relates to the compiled template code:

```
...
var helper, alias1=helpers.helperMissing, alias2="function", alias3=this.escapeExpression;
...
```

I can't seem to find any reason for this code to be added, or any reference to the `helperMissing` function in the Handlebars documentation...

Any insights in to why this might be happening would be extremely welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the problem turned out to be one of conflicting versions!

The way I ended up fixing it was to change the gulp file a little:

```
gulp.task('build-hbs', function(){
  gulp.src('root/app/src/hbs/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars({
      handlebars: require('handlebars')
    }))
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
      namespace: 'Handlebars.templates',
      noRedeclare: true // Avoid duplicate declarations
    }))
    .pipe(insert.prepend('var Handlebars = require("handlebars");\n'))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('root/app/js/templates/'));
});

gulp.task('copy', function(){
  gulp.src('node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.runtime.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('root/app/js/libs/'));
});
```

The main difference is that is specifically loads the version of handlebars installed by `npm` to use as the compiler.

The second job copies the handlebars.runtime.js file from the node_modules folder in to the folder where the browser will actually pick it up.  This guarantees compatibility!

The `wrap` and `declare` calls are required to make sure the compiled code is actually correct (which is different from the information on the handlebars site - the `gulp-handlebars` module just works in a slightly odd way).

Finally the `insert` adds a require call to make sure it works in a stand-alone manner to ensure the `Handlebars` dependency is met at runtime.

Finally, there was an error in my template which should have read:

```
<div id="nick"><b>{{display}}</b></div>
<div id="image">{{gravatar hash 48}}</div>
```

the missing second parameter to the `gravatar` helper caused an error - this only presented itself once the compiled templates were working but was easy to spot at this point!